# Get PropertyInfo of a C# auto property given the backing field

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am implementing a custom IFormatter to serialize objects into a custom format that is required by our legacy systems.

If I declare a C# auto property:

```
[StringLength(15)]
public MyProperty { get; set; }
```

And then in my custom serialize method I get the serialized fields via:

```
MemberInfo[] members = 
    FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(graph.GetType(), Context);
```

How can I access the StringLength attribute that decorates the auto Property?

I am currently getting the property info by taking advantage of the `<PropertyName>k_backingfield` naming convention.  I'd rather not rely on this as it seems to be a specific detail of the C# compiler implementation.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I think you're stuck using the convention, short of dynamically inspecting the IL for each property getter or setter to determine the field referenced.

Comment: Did you try calling [GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254.aspx) on elements of the members array?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - yes, it returns the attributes of the backing field rather than the property.  The is just a code generation attribute that is added automatically by the compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better way would be to stop relying on private fields for serialization (as `FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers` returns) and only use public Properties instead.

It is a **LOT** cleaner and works in this specific case.

But due to legacy code you might want to continue to use `FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers` and in this case, no there is no other options for you other than using the naming convention (Or a little bit of IL analysis) and it may break at each new compiler release.

Just for fun here is some code to do a little bit of IL analysis (It lack ignoring NOOPs and other niceties but should work with most current compilers. If you really adopt such a solution check the [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) library (written by [Jb Evain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36702/jb-evain)) as it contains a full decompiler and it's better than doing it by hand.

It's usage is like this :

```
void Main()
{
    var members = FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(typeof(Foo));
    var propertyFieldAssoc = new PropertyFieldAssociation(typeof(Foo));

    foreach(var member in members)
    {
        var attributes = member.GetCustomAttributes(false).ToList();
        if (member is FieldInfo)
        {
            var property = propertyFieldAssoc.GetProperty((FieldInfo)member);
            if (property != null)
            {
                attributes.AddRange(property.GetCustomAttributes(false));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(member.Name);
        foreach(var attribute in attributes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" * {0}", attribute.GetType().FullName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

And the code :

```
class PropertyFieldAssociation
{
    const byte LDARG_0 = 0x2;
    const byte LDARG_1 = 0x3;
    const byte STFLD = 0x7D;
    const byte LDFLD = 0x7B;
    const byte RET = 0x2A;

    static FieldInfo GetFieldFromGetMethod(MethodInfo getMethod)
    {
        if (getMethod == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("getMethod");

        var body = getMethod.GetMethodBody();
        if (body.LocalVariables.Count > 0) return null;
        var il = body.GetILAsByteArray();
        if (il.Length != 7) return null;

        var ilStream = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(il));

        if (ilStream.ReadByte() != LDARG_0) return null;
        if (ilStream.ReadByte() != LDFLD) return null;
        var fieldToken = ilStream.ReadInt32();
        var field = getMethod.Module.ResolveField(fieldToken);
        if (ilStream.ReadByte() != RET) return null;

        return field;
    }

    static FieldInfo GetFieldFromSetMethod(MethodInfo setMethod)
    {
        if (setMethod == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("setMethod");

        var body = setMethod.GetMethodBody();
        if (body.LocalVariables.Count > 0) return null;
        var il = body.GetILAsByteArray();
        if (il.Length != 8) return null;

        var ilStream = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(il));

        if (ilStream.ReadByte() != LDARG_0) return null;
        if (ilStream.ReadByte() != LDARG_1) return null;
        if (ilStream.ReadByte() != STFLD) return null;
        var fieldToken = ilStream.ReadInt32();
        var field = setMethod.Module.ResolveField(fieldToken);
        if (ilStream.ReadByte() != RET) return null;

        return field;
    }

    public static FieldInfo GetFieldFromProperty(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        if (property == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("property");

        var get = GetFieldFromGetMethod(property.GetGetMethod());
        var set = GetFieldFromSetMethod(property.GetSetMethod());

        if (get == set) return get;
        else return null;
    }

    Dictionary<PropertyInfo, FieldInfo> propertyToField = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, FieldInfo>();
    Dictionary<FieldInfo, PropertyInfo> fieldToProperty = new Dictionary<FieldInfo, PropertyInfo>();

    public PropertyInfo GetProperty(FieldInfo field)
    {
        PropertyInfo result;
        fieldToProperty.TryGetValue(field, out result);
        return result;
    }

    public FieldInfo GetField(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        FieldInfo result;
        propertyToField.TryGetValue(property, out result);
        return result;
    }

    public PropertyFieldAssociation(Type t)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("t");

        foreach(var property in t.GetProperties())
        {
            Add(property);
        }
    }

    void Add(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        if (property == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("property");

        var field = GetFieldFromProperty(property);
        if (field == null) return;
        propertyToField.Add(property, field);
        fieldToProperty.Add(field, property);
    }
}

class StringLengthAttribute : Attribute
{
    public StringLengthAttribute(int l)
    {
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Foo
{
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    string myField;
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string OtherProperty { get { return myField; } set { myField = value; } }
}
```

Comment: There are some public properties that I don't want to serialize.  I realize that I can use the DataMember annotation to only serialize member that explicitly opt-in.  This might be the best solution, but I am going to hold out a little longer before marking this as the answer to see if I get something I like better :p

Comment: @PhilB Added some fun IL analysis code to merit at least a +10 points ^^ (I'm joking, manual binary IL analysis is fun, I never did it before but it's fun)

Comment: Accepted answer for using public properties.  +1 for some fun IL analysis.  I'm going to hand the code off to somebody else in a few months, so I'll probably try to keep it simple, but reading the IL analysis was pretty fun.